# How to get a table td index based on the tr class name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, c#-4.0

I have a table with the below details how to get the td index based on the tr class name

```
<Table id="#Hs_tbl">
    <thead>
        <th>country</th>
        <th>state</th>
        <th>city</th>
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <td>india</td>
        <td class="htInvalid">Bnagalore</td>
        <td class="htInvalid">mysore</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Now need the td tag index of based on the class="htInvalid"; here is what I have tried, I am able to get only one TD name, how to get both td names. Here is my code:

```
var col = $("#Hs_tbl tr").find("td." + "htInvalid").index();
```

How to get both the column name?

Comment: do you have `#` in id attribute of element.

Comment: What are expected results? Code shows index but text says name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either, You need to remove `#` from ID attribute of table.

```
<table id="Hs_tbl">
```

OR, You need to escape `#` meta character in selector like

```
$("#\\#Hs_tbl tr").find("td." + "htInvalid").index()
```

[**Docs**](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as  !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: \\.

To get all the all text, `map()` can be used

```
var alltdtext = $("#\\#Hs_tbl tr").find("td.htInvalid").map(function(){
   return $(this).text();
}).get();
```

Comment: still only will return index of first matched element

Answer (score 0):

First of You need to escape the meta character in id attribute :

```
$("#\\#Hs_tbl tr");
```

or use attribute equals selector:

```
$("[id='#Hs_tbl'] tr")
```

And for getting the text, You can use `.map()` function to get jquery object of text properties of elements along with `.get()` to convert them to array:

```
var alltdtext = $("#\\#Hs_tbl tr").find("td.htInvalid").map(function(){
   return $(this).text();
}).get();
```

**Working Snippet:**

```js
var alltdtext = $("#\\#Hs_tbl tr").find("td.htInvalid").map(function(){
   return $(this).text();
}).get();
console.log(alltdtext);
```

```html
   <Table id="#Hs_tbl">
<thead>
    <th>country</th>
    <th>state</th>
    <th>city</th>
</thead>
<tr>
    <td>india</td>
    <td class="htInvalid">Bnagalore</td>
    <td class="htInvalid">mysore</td>
</tr>
</table>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @chandan: glad it helps. don't forget to accept the helped solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can also directly use the class `.htInvalid` and loop through each of them to get the text & it's index

```
var alltdtext = $(".htInvalid").each(function(){
 var a =$(this).text(); // Bangalore,mysore
 var index  =$(this).index(); //1,2
console.log(a ,index)
})
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/twhsdL7p/1/)